# How can I run Ansible playbook in permitrootlogin disabled machine?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Do I have add to each tasks the ansible `sudo_pass` attributes?
Is there any way to say `sudo` and `sudo_pass` in the playbook?

```
PLAY [testservers] ************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.2.121]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ss                                                                                      h: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/truedeploy_jenkins.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************
192.168.2.121              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have add to each tasks the Ansible `sudo_pass` attribute?

`sudo_pass` has been deprecated in favour of `become_pass` long ago, but that's just a case of naming. The whole family of declarations has been renamed to `become`.

You can, but you don't need to add it to every task.

> Is there any way to say `sudo` and `sudo_pass` in the playbook?

[`become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html) can be defined at play level.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to use `root` as the ansible_user.  Bad idea.  Create a new user, such as `u_ansible`, and give that user `NOPASSWD: ALL` permissions in /etc/sudoers, which you modify with `visudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The best things to do is to use a ssh with private key without password on a user normal account and put this user account in the sudoers with not requiretty.

So you can connect to the remote host and use the become attributes in the tasks of your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend just using the users' own accounts.  It makes tracking who-did-what a lot easier.  In the ansible config file, set `become_ask_pass=True` and Ansible will ask for the users' password.  That way, you do not have to give users `NOPASSWD: ALL` in `/etc/sudoers`.